# Using Domain Accounts on a Domain That You're Not Connected To

Tags: windows, windows-xp, domain, active-directory

Is it possible to use a domain account from a domain other than the one the machine is currently on? (Like for instance, connecting to a network drive that's attached to another domain).

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I do this all the time since i'm in the middle of a domain transition. Mapped drives are probably the easiest thing to do. I'm a command line junkie so i use the net use command:

```
net use <drive_letter|*> <unc_path> /user:<other_domain>\<username>
```

You can also map drives from the windows interface and there is an option to specifiy username.

If i run into a situation that doesn't prompt me for a username you can start a command session under those credentials using:

```
runas /user:<other_domain>\<username> cmd
```

and finally wherever you are asked to authenticat you just need to fully qualify your domain and username. there are a couple of ways to do this:

1. `<domain>\<username>`
2. `<username>@<domain>`

Using these methods I've never had an issue access resources on another domain - although sometimes it's a bit cumbersome to do.

Comment: Thanks for the info. There may be an error with the account then.

Answer (score 0):

AS long as you can authenticate to the source for the network share then yes in theory you can.

if your a member of xyz.local domain and you want to gain access to a network share on abc.local you can do it two ways. 
one - browse to the abc.local share and authenticate against it ( asuming you are allowed to see it) - followed by manually mapping the share.

second way - either using the FQDN or IP address ( if known)  - Click Start - Run - and type  `\\abc.local\` or `\\10.x.x.x\` and then authenticate against it.

as long as your account on that abc.local domain is active and allows you to see the resource you should be able to map it to whichever drive letter you wish.

Comment: Actually my mistake 
it should be \\10.x.x.x 
or \\abc.local
no closing \

Comment: scratch that... closing \ doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be \abc.local\ or \10.x.x.x\ ??

Comment: Never mind... It removed my double "\\" as well... ;-)

Comment: If you put the code in between two ` it will treat it as code and not an escape character.